# How to load a content script on all Google (international) pages?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, internationalization, manifest, content-script

For a Google-Chrome extension, I would like to load a content script on all Google pages. What is the best way to do this?

I tried this, in the `manifest.json`, but it does not work:

```
"matches": ["http://www.google.*/*", "https://www.google.*/*"],
```

This "works" but it is a bit long to write and I do not think it is the best practice:

```
"matches": ["http://www.google.com/*", "https://www.google.com/*", "http://www.google.fr/*", "https://www.google.fr/*", "http://www.google.de/*", "https://www.google.de/*", etc..."],
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See [*Match patterns and globs*](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#matchAndGlob).  Unfortunately, Google-Chrome doesn't have a nice mechanism for top-level-domains (TLD's) in its `matches` specification. So, `http://www.google.*/*` throws an error and `http://www.google.tld/*` ([Greasemonkey syntax](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Magic_TLD)) is not supported.

To work around this, widen the `matches` parameter and filter the results with the `include_globs` parameter.
Like so:

```
"matches":        ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
"include_globs":  ["http://www.google.*/*", "https://www.google.*/*"],
```

Comment: Technically, this answer is bad from a security perspective. That's why Google disallowed the obvious route in the first place.

Comment: Also, to improve it, `"*://..."` means either http or https

Comment: @Xan, the security risk is from the question.  The answer just showed the OP how to do what he wanted.  But, yes, there is a risk that you could get tricked on to a malicious top-level domain, and the extension would try to run. ... Purposely didn't use `"*://..."` so that it wouldn't try to run on `file`, `ftp`, or the once-possible `chrome-extension` and `about` schemes.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. "*://..." is, specifically, a shorthand for `http` and `https` and not all protocols. See [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns). _"If the scheme is *, then it matches either http or https, and not file, or ftp."_

Comment: @Xan. You're right. Guess I missed a chance for an extra simplification.  Consider the existing code "Self documenting" ;) rather than slightly more efficient and noticeably harder to understand at a glance.