# Match pattern for all Google search pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, opera-extension

I'm developing an extension which will perform a certain action on all Google search URLs - but not on other websites or Google pages. In natural language the match pattern is:

- Any protocol (`'*://'`)
- Any subdomain or none (`'www'` or `''`)
- The domain string must equal `'google'`
- Any TLD including three-letter TLDs (e.g. `'.com'`) and multi-part country TLDs (e.g. `'.co.uk'`)
- The first 8 letters of the path must equal `'/search?'`

Many people say 'to match all google search pages use `"*://*.google.com/search?*"` but this is patently untrue as it will not match national TLDs like google.co.uk.

Thus the following code does not work at all:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    alert('This never happens');
  }, {
    urls: [
        "*://*.google.*/search?*",
        "*://google.*/search?*",
    ],
    types: ["main_frame"]
  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Using `"*://*.google.com/search?*"` as the match pattern *does* work, but I fear I would need a list of every single Google localisation for that to be an effective strategy.

Comment: You can get that list as a plain text file from http://www.google.com/supported_domains It currently has 192 entries.

Comment: Good answer, but there seems to be an upper limit of a few dozen on the number of match patterns you can have. 192 entires is several times more match patterns than the listener will accept... :-(

Comment: Here's an interesting idea. Split your domain list and register several (identical) listeners. That would bypass the restriction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, match patterns [do not allow wildcards for TLDs for security reasons](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/faq#faq-dev-16).

> You cannot use wildcard match patterns like `http://google.*/*` to match
>   TLDs (like `http://google.es` and `http://google.fr`) due to the
>   complexity of actually restricting such a match to only the desired
>   domains.
>
> For the example of `http://google.*/*`, the Google domains would be
>   matched, but so would `http://google.someotherdomain.com`. Additionally,
>   many sites do not own all of the TLDs for their domain. For an
>   example, assume you want to use `http://example.*/*` to match
>   `http://example.com` and `http://example.es`, but `http://example.net` is a
>   hostile site. If your extension has a bug, the hostile site could
>   potentially attack your extension in order to get access to your
>   extension's increased privileges.
>
> You should explicitly enumerate the TLDs that you wish to run your
>   extension on.

A slightly unrealistic option would be to list all variants with all national TLDs.

**Edit:** thanks to an incredibly helpful comment by [rsanchez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1507998/rsanchez), here's an [up to date list](http://www.google.com/supported_domains) of all Google domain variants which makes this approach viable.

A realistic option is to inject into a larger set of pages (for instance, all pages), then analyze the URL (with a regexp, for example) and only execute if it matches the pattern you are looking for. Yes, it will be a scarier permissions warning, and you will have to explain it to your users.

Comment: Explicitly enumerating all national TLDs is not slightly unrealistic; it's impossible as there is an upper limit of a few dozen to the number of match patterns the listener will accept. Thanks both for the good answers though!

Comment: Oops, I just noticed you're trying to block requests and not to inject scripts. I didn't really answer your question properly. For your case, you'll just have to implement filtering yourself, yes, in the listener handler. Inefficient, but you can at least salvage it with a match `"*://*/search?*"`, it will be vastly better than no filter at all. Though, you'll also need host permissions; maybe there is no such limitation there.

Comment: In the end I set the extension permissions and background page match pattern to "http://*/search?*" and "https://*/search?*". Then I used the URI.js library (which the extension was already using for other purposes) to manually ensure that the domain was like google.*.

Comment: Does that even work in permissions? They expect hosts. Also, you can use "*://" for protocol to avoid duplication.

Comment: Also, you do NOT want to test for "google.*" for the _exact same_ reasons as why it's not allowed in match patterns. Check against that domain list.

Comment: Yes I liked your original answer and my code specifically checks against that eventuality that you gave. I should have been more specific - using URI.js we first find the national TLD. Then we find the domain. If the domain+tld == URI host part (e.g. if google+.co.uk == google.co.uk) then we assume the site is authorised.  Thus google+.com != the actual google.someattacker.com. You're right that a more elegant solution would use the domain list though.

Answer (score 4):

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16187588/6250024

I was wondering the same and found the same question with a better solution, which introduces the "include_globs" parameters.

```
"matches":        ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
"include_globs":  ["http://www.google.*/*", "https://www.google.*/*"],
```

Comment: here is the link to [Match patterns and globs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#matchAndGlob)

Answer (score 1):

You can use match-pattern arrays of arbitrary length (though it slows down the browser when using more than 1000 or so). For your convenience, here is a updated list:

```json
  "matches": [
    "*://*.google.com/*",
    "*://*.google.ad/*",
    "*://*.google.ae/*",
    "*://*.google.com.af/*",
    "*://*.google.com.ag/*",
    "*://*.google.com.ai/*",
    "*://*.google.al/*",
    "*://*.google.am/*",
    "*://*.google.co.ao/*",
    "*://*.google.com.ar/*",
    "*://*.google.as/*",
    "*://*.google.at/*",
    "*://*.google.com.au/*",
    "*://*.google.az/*",
    "*://*.google.ba/*",
    "*://*.google.com.bd/*",
    "*://*.google.be/*",
    "*://*.google.bf/*",
    "*://*.google.bg/*",
    "*://*.google.com.bh/*",
    "*://*.google.bi/*",
    "*://*.google.bj/*",
    "*://*.google.com.bn/*",
    "*://*.google.com.bo/*",
    "*://*.google.com.br/*",
    "*://*.google.bs/*",
    "*://*.google.bt/*",
    "*://*.google.co.bw/*",
    "*://*.google.by/*",
    "*://*.google.com.bz/*",
    "*://*.google.ca/*",
    "*://*.google.cd/*",
    "*://*.google.cf/*",
    "*://*.google.cg/*",
    "*://*.google.ch/*",
    "*://*.google.ci/*",
    "*://*.google.co.ck/*",
    "*://*.google.cl/*",
    "*://*.google.cm/*",
    "*://*.google.cn/*",
    "*://*.google.com.co/*",
    "*://*.google.co.cr/*",
    "*://*.google.com.cu/*",
    "*://*.google.cv/*",
    "*://*.google.com.cy/*",
    "*://*.google.cz/*",
    "*://*.google.de/*",
    "*://*.google.dj/*",
    "*://*.google.dk/*",
    "*://*.google.dm/*",
    "*://*.google.com.do/*",
    "*://*.google.dz/*",
    "*://*.google.com.ec/*",
    "*://*.google.ee/*",
    "*://*.google.com.eg/*",
    "*://*.google.es/*",
    "*://*.google.com.et/*",
    "*://*.google.fi/*",
    "*://*.google.com.fj/*",
    "*://*.google.fm/*",
    "*://*.google.fr/*",
    "*://*.google.ga/*",
    "*://*.google.ge/*",
    "*://*.google.gg/*",
    "*://*.google.com.gh/*",
    "*://*.google.com.gi/*",
    "*://*.google.gl/*",
    "*://*.google.gm/*",
    "*://*.google.gp/*",
    "*://*.google.gr/*",
    "*://*.google.com.gt/*",
    "*://*.google.gy/*",
    "*://*.google.com.hk/*",
    "*://*.google.hn/*",
    "*://*.google.hr/*",
    "*://*.google.ht/*",
    "*://*.google.hu/*",
    "*://*.google.co.id/*",
    "*://*.google.ie/*",
    "*://*.google.co.il/*",
    "*://*.google.im/*",
    "*://*.google.co.in/*",
    "*://*.google.iq/*",
    "*://*.google.is/*",
    "*://*.google.it/*",
    "*://*.google.je/*",
    "*://*.google.com.jm/*",
    "*://*.google.jo/*",
    "*://*.google.co.jp/*",
    "*://*.google.co.ke/*",
    "*://*.google.com.kh/*",
    "*://*.google.ki/*",
    "*://*.google.kg/*",
    "*://*.google.co.kr/*",
    "*://*.google.com.kw/*",
    "*://*.google.kz/*",
    "*://*.google.la/*",
    "*://*.google.com.lb/*",
    "*://*.google.li/*",
    "*://*.google.lk/*",
    "*://*.google.co.ls/*",
    "*://*.google.lt/*",
    "*://*.google.lu/*",
    "*://*.google.lv/*",
    "*://*.google.com.ly/*",
    "*://*.google.co.ma/*",
    "*://*.google.md/*",
    "*://*.google.me/*",
    "*://*.google.mg/*",
    "*://*.google.mk/*",
    "*://*.google.ml/*",
    "*://*.google.com.mm/*",
    "*://*.google.mn/*",
    "*://*.google.ms/*",
    "*://*.google.com.mt/*",
    "*://*.google.mu/*",
    "*://*.google.mv/*",
    "*://*.google.mw/*",
    "*://*.google.com.mx/*",
    "*://*.google.com.my/*",
    "*://*.google.co.mz/*",
    "*://*.google.com.na/*",
    "*://*.google.com.nf/*",
    "*://*.google.com.ng/*",
    "*://*.google.com.ni/*",
    "*://*.google.ne/*",
    "*://*.google.nl/*",
    "*://*.google.no/*",
    "*://*.google.com.np/*",
    "*://*.google.nr/*",
    "*://*.google.nu/*",
    "*://*.google.co.nz/*",
    "*://*.google.com.om/*",
    "*://*.google.com.pa/*",
    "*://*.google.com.pe/*",
    "*://*.google.com.pg/*",
    "*://*.google.com.ph/*",
    "*://*.google.com.pk/*",
    "*://*.google.pl/*",
    "*://*.google.pn/*",
    "*://*.google.com.pr/*",
    "*://*.google.ps/*",
    "*://*.google.pt/*",
    "*://*.google.com.py/*",
    "*://*.google.com.qa/*",
    "*://*.google.ro/*",
    "*://*.google.ru/*",
    "*://*.google.rw/*",
    "*://*.google.com.sa/*",
    "*://*.google.com.sb/*",
    "*://*.google.sc/*",
    "*://*.google.se/*",
    "*://*.google.com.sg/*",
    "*://*.google.sh/*",
    "*://*.google.si/*",
    "*://*.google.sk/*",
    "*://*.google.com.sl/*",
    "*://*.google.sn/*",
    "*://*.google.so/*",
    "*://*.google.sm/*",
    "*://*.google.sr/*",
    "*://*.google.st/*",
    "*://*.google.com.sv/*",
    "*://*.google.td/*",
    "*://*.google.tg/*",
    "*://*.google.co.th/*",
    "*://*.google.com.tj/*",
    "*://*.google.tk/*",
    "*://*.google.tl/*",
    "*://*.google.tm/*",
    "*://*.google.tn/*",
    "*://*.google.to/*",
    "*://*.google.com.tr/*",
    "*://*.google.tt/*",
    "*://*.google.com.tw/*",
    "*://*.google.co.tz/*",
    "*://*.google.com.ua/*",
    "*://*.google.co.ug/*",
    "*://*.google.co.uk/*",
    "*://*.google.com.uy/*",
    "*://*.google.co.uz/*",
    "*://*.google.com.vc/*",
    "*://*.google.co.ve/*",
    "*://*.google.vg/*",
    "*://*.google.co.vi/*",
    "*://*.google.com.vn/*",
    "*://*.google.vu/*",
    "*://*.google.ws/*",
    "*://*.google.rs/*",
    "*://*.google.co.za/*",
    "*://*.google.co.zm/*",
    "*://*.google.co.zw/*",
    "*://*.google.cat/*"
  ],
```

To recreate, you can use the command

```shell
curl https://www.google.com/supported_domains | sed 's!\(.*\)!"*://*\1/*",!g'
```