# Google chrome extension include_globs not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my google chrome extension i want to insert a JS file in a wild card url using the include_globs but it is not working

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": [
    "http://stackoverflow.com/*"
  ],
  "include_globs": [
    "*google*"
]

  "js": [
    "scripts/content-scripts/utils.js",

  ]
},
```

This script is inserted in stackoverflow but not in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand [how globs work](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#include_globs).

They offer additional filtering *after* `matches` filter is applied.

> `include_globs`
>   array of string
>   Optional. Applied after matches to include only those URLs that **also match this glob**. Intended to emulate the @include Greasemonkey keyword. See Match patterns and globs below for more details.

So your manifest applies to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension` but not `https://www.google.com/` or `http://stackoverflow.com/`

I understand your desire to use a glob: you basically want a `google.*` pattern. That's not allowed due to inherent security risks attached.

You can see the question [Match pattern for all google search pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747781/match-pattern-for-all-google-search-pages) to see why and what are the possible workarounds.

Comment: @Xan, How to use regex for globs? `"include_globs":["/^https?://www\\.example\\.com/.*$/"]` don't seem to work.

Comment: @Pacerier You don't. It's not a regex engine that's behind it - see docs linked for syntax. If you need more powerful processing, you'll need to do it in the script itself after injection.

Comment: @Pacerier Alternatively, use `declarativeContent` API. It allows regex matching. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-PageStateMatcher

Comment: Nevermind the last part. Chrome never took declarative content scripts out of Dev