# Definitive/current list of all google search domains for use in Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, subdomain

I'm working on a Chrome extension that modifies Google search, and would like to restrict it just to Google search domains (e.g. google.com, google.com.au, google.cn, etc).

I found a question [asking for a pattern for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747781/match-pattern-for-all-google-search-pages) but the match patterns for an extension [don't support this](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/match_patterns) and require the last part of a DNS name; so we're stuck with requiring a list of every Google search domain. There are some user-curated lists around the Internet, but I can't find one that's either published by Google, or kept current. Any pointers?

### Edit

Interestingly when I use a list such as from https://github.com/dyne/domain-list/blob/master/data/google in the manifest, it shows up in the Chrome extension as "Read and change your data on all google.com sites" which makes me wonder if there isn't a special match pattern such as `<all_urls>` that is for google.com domains.

Comment: There's no special pattern. I think using lists is perfectly fine. It's not like domains are added every now and then.

Comment: did you just put the entire list in the `matches` field on the manifest? that worked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get that list as a plain text file from https://www.google.com/supported_domains. It currently has 193 entries.